# Trying to compile with gradle bootrun and get cannot find spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I'm running my gradle project with "gradle bootrun" on a cmd prompt window.

The error I get is this:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'kyp4-backend'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml ***<-- PRODUCES 404 ERROR when you go to page***
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom ***<-- PRODUCES 404 ERROR when you go to page***
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar ***<-- PRODUCES 404 ERROR when you go to page***
  >     Required by:
  >      project :

************ GRADLE *****************

So here's my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT") ***<-- THIS DOESN'T EXIST on repo.Spring.io. Only 1.2.0 = 5.x*** or ***<-- on repo.spring.io***
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
//apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'repository'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR3'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time'

    compile group: 'com.myfolder', name: 'all_pfs', version: '7.1.9'
    compile group: 'com.myfolder', name: 'pfs-client', version: '7.1.9'
    compile group: 'com.myfolder.pfs.wic', name: 'pfs-wic', version: '1.1.0.RC3'
    compile group: 'com.picketlink.picketlink', name: 'picketlink-fed', version: '2.0.3-SNAPSHOT'

    compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient'
    compile group: 'xstream', name: 'xstream', version: '1.2.2'
    compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.6.1'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.6.1'

compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.8.3'

compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.13'

compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.2.6.RELEASE'


compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'


testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0'

    compile name: "sqljdbc4-4.0"

    //Added to implement slf4j logger
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.2'                                                                                                                                                                            
    //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-classic', version: '1.0.9'                                                                                                                                                                 
    //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-core', version: '1.0.9' 


// jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra',name: 'cassandra-driver-core',version:'3.2.0'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra')

compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')

compile group: 'com.myfolder.service.fusion.audit.client', name: 'audit-client', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpasyncclient', version: '4.1.3'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

But this is all starting with org.springframework.boot/.context/web.client does not exist:

Here's a couple images to show:
[image: Netbeans showing the SpringFramework doesn't exist]

[image: Right Click on JDK 1.8 showing CLASSES where I added spring]

[image: This shows where the Spring JAR files live based on where Netbeans expects them to live]

I deleted the Netbeans CACHE and let Netbeans rebuild projects and indicies... still, no joy!

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have configured your `buildscript` to use Maven Central as its only repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

You have also configured it to depend on 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of Spring Boot's Gradle Plugin:

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

Snapshots are not published to Maven Central, only releases are published there. Milestones and snapshots are published to https://repo.spring.io. Specifically, snapshots are available from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot and milestones are available from https://repo.spring.io/milestone. You can find 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of Boot's Gradle plugin [here](http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/).

If you want to use a snapshot version of Spring Boot, you should add https://repo.spring.io/snapshot and https://repo.spring.io/milestone to the configured repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
```

The milestone repository is required as a Spring Boot snapshot may have milestone dependencies.

Alternatively, and particularly given that 1.4.0 is rather old now and no longer supported, you may want to upgrade to a more recent release. At the time of writing, 1.5.17.RELEASE is the latest in the 1.x line and 2.1.0.RELEASE is the latest in the 2.x line.

You could upgrade to 1.5.17.RELEASE like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.17.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy! You da man! Thank you. It was the simple things that make it work. Now I'm just needing to find a few JAVA jar files and everything will be right as rain. What I'm having trouble finding are the following:  org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean; and import org.springframework.cassandra.core.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;  What I keep finding is only import org.springframework.data.cassandra which I already have. The problem is, core.keyspace.CreateKeySpaceSpefication and config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean doesn't exist.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'd ask a separate question for that as it appears to be a separate problem. I'd also recommend not adding jars to your JRE's lib directory.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Look for that and I'll give the lowdown on this problem.