# Where do I find the org.springframework.cassandra.config jar. All I see is org.springframework.data.cassandra

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Got the gradle build to work, ([from a previous question related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505727/trying-to-compile-with-gradle-bootrun-and-get-cannot-find-spring-boot-gradle-plu/53508712)) that Andy Wilkinson answered for me, without issue. Working on finding a LONE org.springframework package for Cassandra...

What I'm having trouble finding are the following:

org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean; and import

org.springframework.cassandra.core.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;

What I keep finding is only import 
org.springframework.data.cassandra which I already have. The problem is, core.keyspace.CreateKeySpaceSpefication and config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean doesn't exist.

I've been scouring the internet with no luck although that package I need is still supported.  This is where I may need help from Marcelo.  Once I have that, all the PFS items will build and we'll be in good shape.

Apparently, the community is being forced to use "org.springframework.data.cassandra" which does NOT have the following which appears on this item:
    CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean  For the above, it's 
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean; (Without the Cql)  which is my problem.

The following function does not compile as the methods I need do not exist on the data.cassandra version

```
public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cqlClusterFactoryBean = new CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean();
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setContactPoints(properties.getContactPoints());
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setPort(properties.getPort());
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
    cqlClusterFactoryBean.setQueryOptions(getQueryOptions());
    return cqlClusterFactoryBean;
}
```

The recommendation that Andy also made is that I should not be putting these jar files in my /jdk/jre/lib folder. If that's the case, and the imports don't work, where do I put the jar files to make the project build properly?

I've used JAVA before and built a simple JAVA codebase for a CISCO Appliance and all the imports work great!

We're building this with Gradle and here's my Gradle file for reference that works with help from Andy Wilkinson.

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.17.RELEASE'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
//apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir {
    dirs 'repository'
  }
  mavenCentral()
}



ext {
  springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR3'
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

  compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time'

  compile group: 'com.myproject', name: 'all_pfs', version: '7.1.9'
  compile group: 'com.myproject', name: 'pfs-client', version: '7.1.9'
  compile group: 'com.myproject.pfs.wic', name: 'pfs-wic', version: '1.1.0.RC3'
  compile group: 'com.picketlink.picketlink', name: 'picketlink-fed', version: '2.0.3-SNAPSHOT'

  compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'
  compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient'
  compile group: 'xstream', name: 'xstream', version: '1.2.2'
  compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2'

  compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.6.1'
  compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.6.1'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils
  compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.8.3'



  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl
  compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.9.13'



  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.2.6.RELEASE'


  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox
  compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.11'

  // compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch")
  // compile ("net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0")


  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'


  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4
  testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0'

  compile name: "sqljdbc4-4.0"

  //Added to implement slf4j logger
  compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.2'
  //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-classic', version: '1.0.9'
  //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-core', version: '1.0.9'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
  compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker
  compile group: 'com.itextpdf.tool', name: 'xmlworker', version: '5.5.13'

  // jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

  compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra',name: 'cassandra-driver-core',version:'3.2.0'
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra')

  compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')

  compile group: 'com.myproject.set.fusion.audit.client', name: 'audit-client', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'

  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpasyncclient', version: '4.1.3'

}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}
```

**OF NOTE:**  While I'm scanning the gradle file, I noticed that all my JAR files are "HERE!"  Apparently when I did a CLEAN and BUILD, all my JAR files got put in here. If that's the case, then shouldn't I be able to make the references to all the JAR files I need and then remove them from the /jdk/jre/lib directory?

Thoughts and advice?

Comment: (unrelated) - PDFBox is at 2.0.12. Soon 2.0.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-cassandra', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
```

that should make the org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean available too import.. (i.e. it is contained in spring-data-cassandra-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar which will be pulled down)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was seeking. Much Appreciated!